# Breaking authentication

Tags: linear-algebra

I took this slide off a linear algebra course in coursera.

Could someone explain to me how it works?

[image]

I could not understand how can he compute the passowrd using solver.

Comment: hard to say without knowing what solver is, but presumably it just finds a solution $\hat x$ to $Ax=b$, which will be the password in the case described.

Comment: Yes i guess so. But i am lost at the point starting from m pairs